# Create JS array from HTML cell values?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and Javascript, I managed to create the table and slider how I want them. However I'd like the script to be universal, so it can be used on other tables with different values and with more or less rows. I assume that means it will have to create an array from the number of rows and their values?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>value one</td>
            <td id="value1">0.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value two</td>
            <td id="value2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value three</td>
            <td id="value3">2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="range" id="myRange" defaultvalue="1" value="1" min="0.1" max="2" step="0.1" onclick="myFunction()">
        <input type="button" onclick="myReset();myFunction()" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <script>
        function myReset() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        }

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
            var value1 = 0.5 * x; //entered values manually as I don't know how to retrieve from table cells
            var v1 = value1.toFixed(2);
            var value2 = 5 * x; 
            var v2 = value2.toFixed(2);
            var value3 = 2 * x;
            var v3 = value3.toFixed(2);

            document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = v1;
            document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = v2;
            document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML = v3;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds as though you're looking for a `foreach` loop with something like `document.getElementById('value' + i).innerHTML = (i * x).toFixed(2);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give all the cells the same class you can access them all using [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). You can also assign a value to an attribute of the cell and then access it using [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

Please see the snippet below as an example.

```js
function myReset() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("value-cell");
    
    for(var cell of cells) {
       var value = cell.getAttribute('value');
       cell.innerHTML = value * x;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>value one</td>
            <td class="value-cell" value="0.5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value two</td>
            <td class="value-cell" value="5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value three</td>
            <td class="value-cell" value="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="range" id="myRange" defaultvalue="1" value="1" min="0.1" max="2" step="0.1"
               onclick="myFunction()">
        <input type="button" onclick="myReset(); myFunction()" value="Reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

An alternative to using `.getAttribute` would be to put a [hidden input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) inside the cell and store the value there and then access it with `input.value`.

You could also use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/) and make the whole thing a little cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works exactly how I want it to. Although now that I'm able to move on I've come across an odd situation where if I style the range, the table doesn't consistently update properly when moving the slider. Removing the styling fixes the issue. (Using the latest stable version of Firefox.) And with the CSS found here: [link]https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: This is because you are using `onclick` to trigger the update, and with the new styling the element appears larger than it actually is. I switched it to use `onchange` and it seems to work fine. (The attribute on the Range Input)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out this evening. :)

Answer (score 0):

The icky part is finding a way to iterate through the elements, in this current solution it is assuming the elements will have increasing IDs starting with "value1". Naturally if you add a class to each element you can iterate through that way, but this should suffice to demonstrate the point.

```js
function myReset() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
  var count = 1;
  var currentElem = document.getElementById("value" + count);
  while (currentElem) {
    var val = (currentElem.innerText * x).toFixed(2);
    currentElem.innerHTML = val;
    count++;
    currentElem = document.getElementById("value" + count);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>value one</td>
      <td class="table-val" id="value1">0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value two</td>
      <td class="table-val" id="value2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value three</td>
      <td class="table-val" id="value3">2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="range" id="myRange" defaultvalue="1" value="1" min="0.1" max="2" step="0.1" onclick="myFunction()">
    <input type="button" onclick="myReset();myFunction()" value="Reset">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```